# NodeJS - Axios With Proxy and Auth issues

Tags: node.js, axios, proxy

Hi I have a simple code that sends a Get Request using Axios using Proxy and Auth

```
axios.get(url, {
        "proxy" : {
            "protocol": "http",
            "host": proxy[0],
            "port": proxy[1],
            "auth" : {
                "username": proxy[2],
                "password": proxy[3]
            }
        }
    })
```

This works for a proxy that looks like:
`123.123.123.123:1234:username:password`

However on a proxy that looks like this `something.com:1234:username:password` it throws me an error. The error is usually different for different proxies I use.

Some threw me 503 Errors, some threw me Socket Hung Up Errors.

I suspect it's an issue with the code as I've tried those proxies using Puppeteer and Fogdln and it seems to work. Could it be axios only accept Proxy Hosts in IP?